# Explain the alignment of an array in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, memory-alignment

Consider the following `.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a[2][3] = { 0 };
  
  int i = 1, j = 2;
  int c = 10, d = 20;

  d = c + a[i][j];

  printf("%d\n", d);
  
  return 0;
}
```

In its [LLVM IR form @ Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vzf876d6e), the alignment of the array `a` is `16`:

`%2 = alloca [2 x [3 x i32]], align 16`

Is it possible to explain why it is `16`?